# Custom reader until mark is encountered

Tags: go

After reading a lot about readers/writers in go, I'm now a bit confused on how to implement a custom `io.ReadWriter` that reads (and blocks) until **it is marked as finished**. A sample implementation looks like this:

```
var rw io.ReadWriter // my custom ReadWriter

// write to it in a non blocking way:
go func() {
    fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Line one\n")
    // ...more writes
    fmt.Fprintf(rw, "END") // what would be best to mark the writer as finished???
}()

// read from it and block until **encountering finish mark??**
_, _ = io.Copy(dst, rw)
```

Some related questions:

- How `http.Response.Body` marks the body as finished, so `io.Copy()` knows when to stop reading?
- What would be the best way to mark it as finished?
- Maybe it should also be an `io.Closer`, as the `http.Response.Body`?

These might be silly questions but I can't wrap my head around it after reading for a while. Also there might be a better way to implement this, I don't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to write in one goroutine and read from another, then use an [io.Pipe](https://godoc.org/io#Pipe):

```
r, w := io.Pipe()
go func(w io.WriteCloser) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Line one\n")
    // ...more writes
    w.Close()
}(w)
io.Copy(dst, r)
```

Close the write side of the pipe to indicate that the writer is done.

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/Bi174piVgc)

An io.Reader returns [io.EOF](https://godoc.org/io#EOF) to indicate that no more data is available. The http response body reader returns io.EOF at the end of the body. The read side of the pipe above returns io.EOF after returning all data from the writer.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you making a custom type or just using a normal ReadWriter?

- http.Response.Body is an io.ReadCloser so io.Copy can call its Close()
- To signal the end,have your ReadWriter write an io.EOF to signal it has finished.  You should take a look at ReadCloser (and its usages), so maybe you want an io.ReadWriteCloser.
- Probably

Go's libary code is *very* readable don't be afraid to click on the functions in the documentation to look at the actual source.